# How to zoom UICollectionViewCell like in ios 7 native photo app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, zooming, segue

I have a `UICollectionView` with several cells (about 100x100 pixels). Each cell contains a `UIImageView`.

I want to zoom cell by `pinch gesture` and the open it in full screen (if necessary).
I think I have to use custom transition segue animation between controllers, but how can i handle pinch gesture in the `UICollectionViewController` and then continue to track the user's fingers during the transition animation

Comment: did U find something?

Comment: Yes, but most of the code I had to written myself. I use this as basis: https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery